# add count and percentage in the y-axis

Tags: r, label, categorical-data

How to show the observed count, total count and percentage in the y-axis in brackets below the category name. The variable "sex_vic" is a categorical variable.

[image: something like this]

My code:

```
sur %>%
ggplot(aes(y = sex_vic)) +
geom_bar() +
labs(x = "sex", y = "No of people") +
ggtitle("Sex of victims")
```

My data:

```
structure(list(sex_vic = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -355L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply summarize the data frame and change the label names:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sur %>%
  count(sex_vic) %>%
  mutate(label = paste0(sex_vic, '\n(', n, '/', sum(n), ', ', 
                        scales::percent(n / sum(n), 0.01), ')')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = label)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "sex", y = "No of people") +
  ggtitle("Sex of victims") +
  theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
lab_vec <- sur %>%
    count(sex_vic) %>%
    mutate(labels = paste0(sex_vic,"\n(n=",n, "/",sum(n), ", ", round(n/sum(n)*100,2), "%)")) %>%
    pull(labels)
```

Then add `scale_y_discrete(labels = lab_vec)` onto the end of your `ggplot` call:

```
sur %>%
ggplot(aes(y = sex_vic)) +
geom_bar() +
labs(x = "sex", y = "No of people") +
ggtitle("Sex of victims") + 
scale_y_discrete(labels = lab_vec)
```

[image: plot of data]

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, this works. Can you tell me if there is a way to do this in on step using piping in tidyverse?

Comment: if you want to do it in one step, you can replace the `lab_vec` in `scale_y_discrete(labels = lab_vec)` with `sur %>%
    count(sex_vic) %>%
    mutate(labels = paste0(sex_vic,"\n(n=",n, "/",sum(n), ", ", round(n/sum(n)*100,2), "%)")) %>%
    pull(labels)`